# How to invoke calendar validator on the default value at loading time

Tags: validation, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I have this piece of code. At the moment the validation is invoked by a button. But I do also want to invoke the validation if there is a default value already present there when the page loads. How can I do that? Thanks.

```
// ... the calendar
<div class="formBlock">
    <p class="formGroupTitle">#{msg['startEmploymentDate']}</p>
    <p:message id="startDateMessage" for="startDate" />
    <p:calendar id="startDate" required="true" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy"
            locale="de" requiredMessage="#{nts['pleaseEnterAFutureDate']}"
            mindate="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.currentDate}"
            value="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.jobProfile.startDate}"
            converterMessage="#{nts['pleaseEnterAFutureDate']}"
            validator="futureDateValidator" showOn="button" navigator="true">
            <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="@(.roundedNumberRefreshable)"
                    listener="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.updateSearchParameters()}" />
    </p:calendar>
</div>

// ... and the button
<p:commandButton
    value="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.getJobProfile().ams ? msg['sendProposal'] : msg['accept']}"
    oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {PF('generalDetailsSlider').unselect(0);PF('paymentDetailsSlider').select(0);}"
    update="@(.adtextUpdateable) @(.hasAddressAndMessageUpdateable) startDate vacancies startDateMessage vacanciesMessage @(.generalDetailsSliderHeaderUpdateable) @(.progressBarCompany)"
    actionListener="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.verifyHasAddresses()}"
    process="startDate vacancies" partialSubmit="true"></p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Why don't you just validate it in your init method of your backing bean?

Comment: @pablo: Suppose you want to validate all fields this way, then you are duplicating functionality.

Comment: Well, you already got the code isolated in an specific validator that you can reuse, right?

Comment: Still, validate for what fields etc (which is either in the UI or on the model and implicitly used by the UI) would require duplication. So while it might work, I'm very curious if it would be possible to e.g. force a 'validation phase' before the render phase on the initial request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got an idea which might work by using a `remoteCommand` (A little hack). Basically you will simulate what will happen when the submit button is clicked. You can decide when you want to call your function.

Hope this helps.

```
<p:remoteCommand name="errorSubmitButton" autoRun="false/true" global="false"
                oncomplete="if (args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {PF('generalDetailsSlider').unselect(0);PF('paymentDetailsSlider').select(0);}"
                update="@(.adtextUpdateable) @(.hasAddressAndMessageUpdateable) startDate vacancies startDateMessage vacanciesMessage @(.generalDetailsSliderHeaderUpdateable) @(.progressBarCompany)"
                actionListener="#{companyJobProfileCreateStep2Bean.verifyHasAddresses()}"
                process="startDate vacancies" partialSubmit="true" />

<h:outputScript rendered="yourConditionWhenToExecuteScriptIfYouHaveOne">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            errorSubmitButton();
        });
</h:outputScript>
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I did some slight modifications, but it does the job.